# how to import dictionary from file1.py to file2.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I have two python files in the project file1.py and file2.py. 
A python dictionary in file1 gets the values after running the code. Before that it is empty. I want that dictionary in file2.

I tried to import that dictionary via `from file1 import dictionary`,
but its output is a blank dictionary.

*file1.py*

```
def function(f_act)
    some code that adds values to dictionary
return f_act

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f_act = defaultdict(dict)
    f_act = function(f_act)
```

*file2.py*

```
import file1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print file1.f_act
```

If I run file1 individually, the dictionary prints value, but while importing, dictionary is blank. I also tried changing `if __name__ == '__main__':` to `if __name__ == '__file1__':`. Dictionary is still blank while printing.

Initially the dictionary is blank. The dictionary should print values which are assigned in the function in file1.

Comment: Make sure your post the code, which absolute your code. because of your `return` statement out of your `function`.

Comment: cannot reproduce. Here it works properly.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that `file2.py` is your main module (the one that you'll run from the command line). Then you should remove the `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement from `file1.py`. Your `file1.py` should either only contain the dictionary, or the function to populate the dictionary.

```py
# file1
def populate_dictionary(d):
    pass
```

and from `file2` you import that function with:

```py
from .file1 import populate_dictionary

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f_act = default_dict(dict)
    print(populate_dictionary(f_act)
```

Another solution would be to create the dictionary inside `file1` and import the dictionary into `file2`:

```py
from .file1 import f_act
```